# google web tookit with google plugin for eclipse v3.8.0 cannot debug

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have been using GWT for a while and I suddenly started having problem with debugging when I updated my google plugin for eclipse to v3.8.0

When I put breakpoint and run as debug, it does not break at all.
I also do System.out.println and it does not print out anything.
I am running this locally and it used to work when I was using previous version of google plugin for eclipse.

I am using "RUN AS , Web Application(GWT Super Dev Mode) since other modes does not work. This is new in google plugin for eclipse v3.8

I also tried for hours to get my previous google plugin for evclispe but cannot find it.

I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4, and also tried this in Eclipse 4.3 but both does not work.

Does anyone have same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Super Dev Mode. To debug inside Eclipse install the SDBG-plugin from here:

https://github.com/sdbg/sdbg

Or debug inside your browser (Chrome) as described here:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-gwt-super-dev-mode

Your log message will be printed to the browser console.